# Why are the recommendations locked

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In the duty tab, I cannot access the recommendations. They are locked and when I click on it it says that this command is not available at the moment.

How can I access these recommended duties?

Comment: Where are you when you tried to click on them?  There's a few spots where there are no quests, so you can't use recommendations.

Comment: I'm in the major city where I started. There are many quests in that area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must complete the set of tutorial quests before the Recommendation List functionality is unlocked.  Just keep working on your main storyline quests.  They are the ones that have this icon:

[image]

Comment: By the way, almost all functionnalities of ffxiv are unlocked by following the main quest-line. Something missing? keep doing the storyline.